# Why move ctor is not called in this case?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, stdmove

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    
    Test(string value){
        cout<<"Ctor "<<value<<endl;
        _val=value;
    }
    Test( Test&& mv): _val(mv._val)
    {
        mv._val=string();
        cout<<"Mv constructor"<<endl;  
    }
    
    string& get()
    {
      return this->_val;
    }
private:
    string _val;
};

void print(Test&& t)
{
    cout<<"Stampa val is "<<t.get()<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Test a{"ciao"};
    print(move(a));
    cout<<"Val of a is "<<a.get()<<endl;
    print(Test("test"));
    

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is (adding line numbers to stdout):

Ctor ciao 
Stampa val is ciao 
Val of a is ciao 
Ctor test 
Stampa val is test

Why at line 2 in main the mv semantic is not called? I might understand at line four there is an optimisation so the constructor only is called but, I can't explain the first move. Any ideas?

Comment: `std::move()` only casts to an rvalue, it doesn't do anything really.

Comment: Because there is no need to copy/move Test instance when calling `print`. `print` takes Rvalue reference, and you pass Rvalue reference casting `a` by `move`. BTW, fix your move ctor: `_val(std::move(mv._val))`.

Comment: Move constructor is a constructor, which means it constructs a new object. In `print(move(a));` statement, there is simply no new object involved, so there is consequently no constructor called.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) just converts argument to rvalue (which could be *moved* later), it doesn't perform move operation itself. The converted rvalue is bound to the reference parameter `t`, so the move constructor isn't invoked in this case.

> std::move is used to indicate that an object t may be "moved from", i.e. allowing the efficient transfer of resources from t to another object.
>
> In particular, std::move produces an xvalue expression that identifies its argument t. It is exactly equivalent to a static_cast to an rvalue reference type.

Move constructor is typically called to initialize an object, it won't be called in reference binding (it's true for lvalue-reference too). If you change the parameter to be passed by-value, move constructor would be used (to initialize the parameter). E.g.

```
void print(Test t)
{
    cout<<"Stampa val is "<<t.get()<<endl;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mVVqEkWoSsPz3UcA)

---

BTW: Even after change to pass-by-value `print(Test("test"));` doesn't invoke move constructor because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

BTW2: In the move constructor it's better to move initialize data member `val` based on move operation provided by `std::string`. E.g.

```
Test( Test&& mv): _val(std::move(mv._val))
{
    cout<<"Mv constructor"<<endl;  
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! But after the conversion why shouldn't it be called? Is it an optimisation, is it not expected to call the move semantic? Or is this the case where we use the double && to say we jsut expect an rvalue therefore the mv constructor is not called?

Comment: @HDenied Answer revised.

Comment: @HDenied `T&&` is a reference to a `T`. It only differs from `T&` in what can be bound to the reference

Comment: @songyuanyao thanks, the part related to initialisation and reference binding in particular made me understand the concept

Answer (score 1):

There are only two `Test` objects constructed in your code, not more.

```
int main()
{
    Test a{"ciao"};                          // here 
    print(move(a));
    cout<<"Val of a is "<<a.get()<<endl;
    print(Test("test"));                     // and here
}
```

The second also constructs the object via `Test(string)` constructor. `std::move` does not construct an object, it is merely a cast to a rvalue reference. Passing that rvalue reference to `print` also does not require to construct another `Test`. If you want to call the constructor you have to actually construct an instance, for example:

```
 auto t  = Test( std::move(a) );     // calls Test(Test&&)
 auto t2 = Test( Test("move me") );  // calls Test(string) then Test(Test&&)
```